# Выбор книги для создания приложений под Android (клиент для сервера)

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер, книги

С какой книги посоветуете начать изучение (желательно сразу на 4 версии).

Важно что бы была глава про то как парсить json с сервера или какие нибудь уроки на эту тему. Так как приложение будет завязано на сервер.

Хочется написать не сильно функциональное приложение (пока что вход, отображение информации для пользователей с сервера), но красивое со стандартными рекомендациями по интерфейсу от Google.

Надеюсь есть подобные книги, или статьи которые помогут мне реализовать что требуется.

Comment: > Важно что бы была глава про то как парсить json с сервера или какие нибудь уроки на эту тему. Так как приложение будет завязано на сервер.

Простите, а просто [у гугла](https://www.google.ru/search?q=java+json) не спросить?

Comment: Для того, что-бы просто начать не нужна книга, более того, если вам нужно простенькое приложение будет достаточно просто немного почитать статеек типа android getting started и т.п., ну а потом, можно будет первое время немного практиковать SODD, главное не увлекаться, ну а потом уже можно и книгу почитать. Ну и - для того что-бы найти ответ на вопрос типа как парсить JSON на X языке/X платформе достаточно просто спросить у гугла, книжки же нужны скорее для получения каких-то концептуальных знаний типа как работает android приложение, что такое activity etc.

Comment: В общем и целом книжка вообще не обязательна для того, что-бы даже стать полноценным и даже хорошим android разработчиком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот неплохой [туториал](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/RottenTomatoes-Networking-Tutorial) про получение и парсинг json данных с сервера.
Так же там много друих статей в [wiki](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki)